# easy and fast way to convert an int to binary?

Tags: c#

What I am looking for is something like PHPs `decbin` function in C#. That function converts decimals to its representation as a string.

For example, when using `decbin(21)` it returns `10101` as result.

I found [this function](http://www.globalguideline.com/articles/analysis.php?k=Converting_Between_Binary_and_Decimal_in_C_sharp) which basically does what I want, but maybe there is a better / faster way?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

```
var result = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
```

– Almost the only use for the (otherwise useless) `Convert` class.

Comment: Wow, there is another use as Convert that Convert.ToDateTime !!
Very nice.

Comment: LOL, always usefull when you do reflection and generic type conversion  but funny !

Answer (score 31):

Most ways will be better and faster than the function that you found. It's not a very good example on how to do the conversion.

The built in method `Convert.ToString(num, base)` is an obvious choice, but you can easily write a replacement if you need it to work differently.

This is a simple method where you can specify the length of the binary number:

```
public static string ToBin(int value, int len) {
   return (len > 1 ? ToBin(value >> 1, len - 1) : null) + "01"[value & 1];
}
```

It uses recursion, the first part (before the +) calls itself to create the binary representation of the number except for the last digit, and the second part takes care of the last digit.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToBin(42, 8));
```

Output:

```
00101010
```

Comment: Thanks, also very nice option! I already suspected that the function I found was not the best way to do it.

Comment: +1 for recursion. Although I really don’t like the usage of `null` there, and `""` works just as well.

Comment: Although your example is a good illustration, note that this particular function could be implemented more simply and efficiently as: `string s = Convert.ToString(value, 2); return new string('0', len - s.Length) + s;` (assuming the binary number fits in the provided length)

Answer (score 10):

```
int toBase = 2;
string binary = Convert.ToString(21, toBase); // "10101"
```

Answer (score 5):

To have the binary value in (at least) a specified number of digits, padded with zeroes:

```
string bin = Convert.ToString(1234, 2).PadLeft(16, '0');
```

The Convert.ToString does the conversion to a binary string.
The PadLeft adds zeroes to fill it up to 16 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```
    static bool[] Dec2Bin(int value)
    {
        if (value == 0) return new[] { false };
        var n = (int)(Math.Log(value) / Math.Log(2));
        var a = new bool[n + 1];
        for (var i = n; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            n = (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
            if (n > value) continue;
            a[i] = true;
            value -= n;
        }
        Array.Reverse(a);
        return a;
    }
```

Using Pow instead of modulo and divide so i think it's faster way.