# Converting Decimal to Binary C# using functions

Tags: c#, function, binary, decimal

I want to make a converter for decimal to binary using a function but I don't see what is wrong with my code: (the errors states that i can not simplicity convert string to char but I have converted it in line 12). Edit - I am interested in the process of converting denary to binary rather than the output.

```
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Decimal 14 = Binary " + dec_to_bin(14));
     Console.WriteLine("Decimal 100 = Binary " + dec_to_bin(100));
     Console.WriteLine("Decimal 32 = Binary " + dec_to_bin(32));
     Console.WriteLine("Decimal 64 = Binary " + dec_to_bin(64));
     Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string dec_to_bin(int dec)
    {
     string binary = "11111111";
     char[]binaryArray = binary.ToCharArray();

     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
      if (dec % 2 == 0)
      {
       binaryArray[i] = "0"; // error 1
      }
      else 
      {
       binaryArray[i] = "1"; // error 2
      }
     }

     binary = new string(binaryArray);
     return binary;

   }
```

Comment: You might want to call it "integer to binary" since there is a specific `Decimal` type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [easy and fast way to convert an int to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838963/easy-and-fast-way-to-convert-an-int-to-binary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to binary conversion in c #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954962/decimal-to-binary-conversion-in-c)

Comment: To add to mjwills comment above: When you ask a question about an exception you encounter, it is always a good idea to include its stacktrace to the question. Makes it easier to analyse the problem and it will be asked for, anyway.

Comment: @mjwills I wanted to code it myself, I'm more interested in knowing how it works rather than the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`binaryArray[i] = "0"` must be `binaryArray[i] = '0'`

`"0"` is a `string` literal while `'0'` is a `char` and you have an array of `char`.

Same for `binaryArray[i] = "1"`

---

While the above will solve your problem, I recommend using `Convert.ToString(dec, 2)` (as suggested by the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1838988/982149) marked by mjwills). Of course, this makes only sense if you are interested in the outcome rather than in coding it yourself.

---

Mind that I deliberately did not address any other issues with the code snippet.